# What is the REACT QUERY way to reuse global state?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

In redux/context api, we used to fetch the data and save in the global state once. Then we could reuse the global state throuhout the app.For ex: USER auth state that holds user id,token etc. I wanted to know that what is the react query way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just call `useQuery` wherever you want to access the data. The cache is globally available, just like the redux store is globally available.

I've blogged about this extensively, e.g. here:
https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-as-a-state-manager

Comment: cache will be available for 5 minutes or any time we need ?  and useQuery is for GETquery what about useMutation I need POST data to be stored and re user later ??
can u help me on that :)

Comment: Cache time is default to 5 minutes but can be modified us you wish. useMutation is meant to emit side effects when modifying data ie update/post/patch. You can just use r-q complex query key for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use useQuery and access the state in any component, or even modify the state with useMutation. However, keep in mind that react query is essentially a server state management tool. If used as a client state management, it may eventually lead to issues. For example, after refreshing the browser, you would lose the data saved into useQuery. So I think it would be more appropriate to use a client state management like redux/context api with react query if needed.